# Getting Street address in android using GPS and google maps

Tags: android, gps, maps

I wan't to get the street name that I'm standing in using the GPS of my android and google maps.
can you please help me?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use the Geocoder class - there's some useful functions like `getFromLocation` for example. Give the method longitude and latitude and function returns list of addresses that are known to describe the area immediately surrounding the given latitude and longitude. More information about [Geocoder class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html)